# VBA macro to control cursor within Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I normally use VBA within Excel but this time I need something for Word.

I want to be able to keep the cursor on a particular line within the screen by scrolling the document rather than moving the cursor.

1. Is there an event I can trap, or is there a function that can be written, which scrolls the document up rather than moving the cursor down, when typing would normally move it to the next line?
2. Instead of UpArrow, DnArrow, PgUp, PgDn, etc. moving the cursor in the standard direction, scrolling the document in the opposite direction to achieve the same effect but to leave the cursor on the same line of the screen.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.window.smallscroll ?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.window.largescroll ?

Comment: Keeping the cursor on a particular line is controlling the cursor. Thanks for the links. I understand the methods but how do I intercept would-be cursor movement to call the methods instead?

Comment: There is no event that occurs when the window scrolls.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.